# Plot histogram normalized by fixed parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I need to plot a plot a *normalized* histogram (by *normalized* I mean divided by a fixed value) using the `histtype='step'` style.

The issue is that `plot.bar()` doesn't seem to support that style and if I use instead `plot.hist()` which does, I can't (or at least don't know how) plot the *normalized* histogram.

Here's a MWE of what I mean:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rand_data():
    return np.random.uniform(low=10., high=20., size=(200,))

# Generate data.
x1 = rand_data()

# Define histogram params.
binwidth = 0.25
x_min, x_max = x1.min(), x1.max()
bin_n = np.arange(int(x_min), int(x_max + binwidth), binwidth)

# Obtain histogram.
hist1, edges1 = np.histogram(x1, bins=bin_n)
# Normalization parameter.
param = 5.

# Plot histogram normalized by the parameter defined above.
plt.ylim(0, 3)
plt.bar(edges1[:-1], hist1 / param, width=binwidth, color='none', edgecolor='r')
plt.show()
```

(notice the normalization: `hist1 / param`) which produces this:

[image]

I can generate a `histtype='step'` histogram using:

```
plt.hist(x1, bins=bin_n, histtype='step', color='r')
```

and get:

[image]

but then it wouldn't be *normalized* by the `param` value.

Comment: @tcaswell would you mind posting the comment as an answer? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on tcaswell's comment (use [step](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.step)) I've developed my own answer. Notice that I need to add elements to both the `x` (one zero element at the beginning of the array) and `y` arrays (one zero element at the beginning and another at the end of the array) so that `step` will plot the vertical lines at the beginning and the end of the bars.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rand_data():
    return np.random.uniform(low=10., high=20., size=(5000,))

# Generate data.
x1 = rand_data()

# Define histogram params.
binwidth = 0.25
x_min, x_max = x1.min(), x1.max()
bin_n = np.arange(int(x_min), int(x_max + binwidth), binwidth)

# Obtain histogram.
hist1, edges1 = np.histogram(x1, bins=bin_n)
# Normalization parameter.
param = 5.

# Create arrays adding elements so plt.bar will plot the first and last
# vertical bars.
x2 = np.concatenate((np.array([0.]), edges1))
y2 = np.concatenate((np.array([0.]), (hist1 / param), np.array([0.])))

# Plot histogram normalized by the parameter defined above.
plt.xlim(min(edges1) - (min(edges1) / 10.), max(edges1) + (min(edges1) / 10.))
plt.bar(x2, y2, width=binwidth, color='none', edgecolor='b')
plt.step(x2, y2, where='post', color='r', ls='--')

plt.show()
```

and here's the result:

[image]

The red lines generated by `step` are equal to those blue lines generated by `bar` as can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

The step plot will generate the appearance that you want from a set of bins and the count (or normalized count) in those bins.  Here I've used plt.hist to get the counts, then plot them, with the counts normalized.  It's necessary to duplicate the first entry in order to get it to actually have a line there.

```
(a,b,c) = plt.hist(x1, bins=bin_n, histtype='step', color='r')
a = np.append(a[0],a[:])
plt.close()
step(b,a/param,color='r')
```

This is not quite right, because it doesn't finish the plot correctly. the end of the line is hanging in free space rather than dropping down the x axis.

you can fix that by adding a 0 to the end of 'a' and one more bin point to b

```
a=np.append(a[:],0)
b=np.append(b,(2*b[-1]-b[-2]))
step(b,a/param,color='r')
```

lastly, the ax.step mentioned would be used if you had used

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

to give you access to the figure and axis directly. For examples, see http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo_bounds.html

Comment: There is a kwarg 'where' that controls how it draws. And us np.histogram not hist to get the bins